# No converter for [class org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.SystemHealth] with preset Content-Type 'null'

Tags: spring-boot-actuator

I am facing this below issue.. when i start hitting the http://localhost:8080/actuator/health url.
May i know any one faced the same issue? I am unable figure out the issue.

ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet].log - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter for [class org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.SystemHealth] with preset Content-Type 'null'] with root cause
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter for [class org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.SystemHealth] with preset Content-Type 'null'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem when I was creating a specific unit test class with Spring Boot 3.2.0.

You can see a problem close to you with the same error message [here](https://itecnote.com/tecnote/java-springboot-httpmessagenotwritableexception-no-converter-for-with-preset-content-type-null/). In that case, it's caused by Jackson Format

In my case, the problem is related to the absence of [WebMvcAutoConfiguration class - Spring Boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration.html) which brings a converter. If you use @SpringBootTest annotation above your Unit test class, it'll bring automatically. But in my case - the problem ocurred when I decided to creat a unit test class with the focus on to check only Spring Boot Actuator configuration according to every endpoint declared at my application.yaml. The target of the unit test class is to avoid accidentally misconfiguration during an update or regressions and to expose an endpoint irregurlarly. The Unit Test class created by me was to avoid loading all ApplicationContext inheritance by @SpringBootApplication which load all [Spring Boot available Auto-configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using.html#using.auto-configuration)

```
package br.com.test.controller;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.availability.AvailabilityHealthContributorAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.availability.AvailabilityProbesAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.EndpointAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.WebEndpointAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.health.HealthEndpointAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.info.InfoEndpointAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.ManagementContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.server.ManagementContextAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.PingHealthIndicator;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.availability.ApplicationAvailabilityBean;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers.print;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath;

/**
 * Unit test specialized on to check Spring Boot Actuator configurations at the artifact.
 * We configure to expose only some endpoints, for example, /health, if any configuration has changed, then it'll
 * check the regression.
 */
@SpringBootTest(
        classes = HealthCheckControllerTest.CustomApplicationContext.class,
        properties = {
                "management.endpoint.health.group.liveness.include=livenessState",
                "management.endpoint.health.group.readiness.include=readinessState"})
class HealthCheckControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.context).build();
    }

    @Test
    void requisitaEndpointHealth_ViaGet_deveRetornar200ComServicoUP()
            throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/health"))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.status").value("UP"));
    }

    @Test
    void requisitaEndpointHealthLiveness_ViaGet_deveRetornar200ComServicoUP()
            throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/health/liveness"))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.status").value("UP"));
    }

    @Test
    void requisitaEndpointHealthReadiness_ViaGet_deveRetornar200ComServicoUP()
            throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/health/readiness"))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.status").value("UP"));
    }

    /**
     * That class allows to turn available only some Spring Boot Actuator Auto-configurations.
     *
     * By default, @SpringBootApplication loads all resources unnecessarily declared as spring boot dependencies
     * (starters).
     *
     * <a href="https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using.html#using.auto-configuration">...</a>
     *
     */
    @Configuration
    @ManagementContextConfiguration
    @Import({
            EndpointAutoConfiguration.class,
            HealthEndpointAutoConfiguration.class,
            InfoEndpointAutoConfiguration.class,
            WebEndpointAutoConfiguration.class,
            ManagementContextAutoConfiguration.class,
            HealthCheckControllerTest.class,
            AvailabilityHealthContributorAutoConfiguration.class,
            AvailabilityProbesAutoConfiguration.class,
            PingHealthIndicator.class,
            ApplicationAvailabilityBean.class,
            MockMvcAutoConfiguration.class,
            WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class // I included it manually and solved
    })
    public class CustomApplicationContext {

    }

}
```

I hope you solve your problem. Thanks.